# How to use table data as a parameter in Tableau's R integration?

Tags: r, tableau-api

I would like to know how to use table data as a parameter in Tableau's R integration.

**Example**

Tableau  has a builtin data set called "Superstore" used for reproducible examples. Suppose I've used the Superstore data set to create a "text table" (i.e. spreadsheet) with `Region` as rows and `SUM(Profit)` as the data.

That looks like this:

[image]

Now, suppose I wanted to pass the data in this table to R for a calculation. I would start Rserve

```
library(Rserve)
Rserve()
```

and establish a connection with Tableau's UI.

Next I would want to create a calculated field to send the data to R and retrieve the results. I'm not sure how to do this.

My attempt looks like this:

```
SCRIPT_REAL('
    output <- anRFunction(.arg1)
',
[someTableauMeasure])
```

which should be fine, except that I don't know how to represent the table data where it currently says `someTableauMeasure`. This is just an arbitrary example, but a reason I might want to do this is that I might provide the user with a filter, such as `Country`, so that they could filter the results at will and get an updated result from R.

For testing purposes that function `anRFunction` could be replaced with something like `abs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tableau will pass the aggregated values to R, depending on the settings of your worksheet.

So in your case if you use:

```
SCRIPT_REAL('
    output <- anRFunction(.arg1)
',
sum(Profit))
```

You will get the output according to the dimensions you have on your worksheet, in your case `[Region]` if you set up a filter by country, R will only receive and return the values for a certain country and if you choose to use `[Category]` instead, you will get the results of your R function broken down by category.

Comment: Oh ok, so the filtering is automatically added in then.